# MIPS - printing a string without pseudo instructions

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I've got a few strings I'd like to print in MIPS, but it must be done without any pseudo instructions. I'm having a lot of difficulty finding where the beginning of the string is. Here is the code:

```
   .globl main


    .data

terminal_prompt:
    .asciiz "Enter Integers: " #17 chars

prompt0:
    .asciiz "Smallest int: "
prompt1:
    .asciiz "\nLargest int: "
prompt2:
    .asciiz "\nQuotient: "
prompt3:
    .asciiz "\nRemainder: "

    .text
main:
    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    lui $a0, 0x1000
    ori $a0, $zero, 17
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall
```

I would think that the second string prompt0 begins at offset 17, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the memory segment:

```
[10000000]    65746e45  6e492072  65676574  203a7372    E n t e r   I n t e g e r s :   
[10000010]    616d5300  73656c6c  6e692074  00203a74    . S m a l l e s t   i n t :   . 
[10000020]    72614c0a  74736567  746e6920  0a00203a    . L a r g e s t   i n t :   . . 
[10000030]    746f7551  746e6569  0a00203a  616d6552    Q u o t i e n t :   . . R e m a 
[10000040]    65646e69  00203a72  00000000  00000000    i n d e r :   . . . . . . . . . 
[10000050]..[1003ffff]  00000000
```

Comment: Note your dump is using hex but the code uses decimal. Also, your dump is showing 4 byte integers in little endian format. So yeah, 17 looks correct. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @Jester Unfortunately I keep getting a "memory out of bounds" error.

Comment: Yes, because you used `ori $a0, $zero, 17` instead of `ori $a0, $a0, 17`. So you destroyed the top bits. The simulator/debugger should have shown you that the wrong value ends up in `$a0`.

Comment: Yikes, that's a really dumb mistake. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Single step is your friend!  As you single step, verify the values produced by arithmetic instructions, and control flow resulting from branches.